# pass small number into awk inside shell not working

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want to write a wrapper script that takes a small number, say, 1e-3 and use it as a cutoff to select certain rows of data.

Suppose I have an input.txt

```
region  p-value
brain   0.009
breast  0.001
liver   1e-7
skin    1e-6
```

I want to select regions with a p-value smaller than 1e-5 which are liver and skin from my toy example.

My script currently looks like select.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
column=$2
cutoff=$3

awk -v a="$column" -v b="$cutoff" '{ if (a < b) print}' $file > $file'.'$cutoff
```

I would run like this:

```
bash select.sh input.txt 2 1e-5
```

This doesn't work... However, if I directly type awk line on terminal, it works.

```
 awk '{if ($2 < 1e-5) print}' input.txt > input.1e-5
```

So I know it's probably something about awk in shell environment that I'm not aware of. Does anyone know how to solve it?

Update: I tried to pass 0.00001 into the command and it didn't work either.

Thanks!

Comment: `"$file.$cutoff"` would be better than `$file'.'$cutoff`, which will break badly if either name contains a wildcard, whitespace, a character contained in the current value of IFS, etc.

Comment: i see. thanks, will use "$file.$cutoff"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing `$` in the call of `if (a<b)`: if you want to refer to the column number `a`, you have to say `$a`.

Just do:

```
awk -v a="$column" -v b="$cutoff" '{ if ($a < b) print}' $file > $file'.'$cutoff
                                         ^
```

Or even shorter:

```
awk -v a="$column" -v b="$cutoff" '$a < b' "$file" > "$file.$cutoff"
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                    Charles Duffy's security check
```

Comment: I'm not sure I know awk well enough to grok this -- why is a `$` needed referring to `a` but not `b`?

Comment: The key here is that `a` contains the number and you need the value in that field. So you need `$a` to get that. Same reason you need `$2` and not `2` or `$NF` vs. `NF`.

Comment: Because `$a` refers to the field number `a`, whereas `b` is a variable to which we compare the value. That is: awk's columns are named `$1`, `$2`, ..., whereas awk's variables do not have leading `$`.

Comment: Took the liberty of adding quotes around the first `$file` as well.